# Which method is more correct for removing WooCommerce Extensions menu item?

Tags: functions, filters, woocommerce-offtopic, actions, admin-menu

Both of these methods remove and restrict access to the WooCommerce "Extensions" menu page in the admin, which is what I want. But **which method is more ideal?**

By *removing* it (option 1) or by *overriding* the filter that creates it (option 2)?

Both options seem to work fine.

**Option 1:**

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'fs_remove_admin_menu_links', 999);
function fs_remove_admin_menu_links(){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( $user && isset($user->user_email) && 'tester@example.com' == $user->user_email ) {
        remove_submenu_page('woocommerce', 'wc-addons');
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
function fs_new_remove_admin_menu_links() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( $user && isset($user->user_email) && 'tester@example.com' == $user->user_email ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_addons_page', 'fs_new_remove_admin_menu_links' );
```

The goal is just to prevent access to the page for a certain user.

It seems to be added via the WooCommerce plugin by a function that includes:

```
if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_addons_page', true ) ) {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'addons_menu' ), 70 );
}
```

Comment: the filter looks like be made for removing acces to this page then I would use that. but instead of testing the e-mail adress, you can test a role then you can give this role to more users with no needs to edit the code.

Comment: The end goal is to remove this page for everyone who doesn't have a registered email address with a certain domain (e.g., everyone outside of Example Company). So here is what I've decided to use for now: https://gist.github.com/Garconis/3674f897893589f55ab6e17e3a0dd605